# PHP Ajax Login, Ajax not working after successful login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, authentication

I have this javascript. Which is loggin me correctly but
the ajax call executed in the success callback of the login ajax call
is not being executed

```
$('.js-div-signin form').submit(function(){
    $form = $(this);
    $isValid = $(this).validate({
        rules: {
            email:'required email',
            password:'required'
        }
    });

    if($isValid.form()) {
        $data = {
            email:$('.js-input-email',$form).val(),
            password:$('.js-input-password',$form).val(),
            remember:$('.js-input-remember:checked',$form).val()
        };

        $('input', $form).attr('disabled','disabled');

        $.ajax({
            url:'/ajax/login',
            data:$data,
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(res){
                if(res.type == 'success') {
                    /**
                     * This is the ajax call not working
                     */
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'/ajax/getheader',
                        dataType:'html',
                        success:function($html){
                            $('#header').html($html);
                        } error:function(a, b) {
                            console.log(a);
                            console.log(b);
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    showError(res.message);
                    $('.js-input-password',$form).val('');
                    $('input', $form).removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('.js-input-password',$form).focus();
                }
            }, error:function(){
                showError('Email or Password incorrect');
                $('.js-input-password',$form).val('');
                $('input', $form).removeAttr('disabled');
                $('.js-input-password',$form).focus();
            }
        });
    }

    return false;

});
```

I get this logs in the console, which mean the second ajax call to
getheader fails but the error doesn't provide information at all

```
> Object
Error
```

Any ideas?

I guess this bug can be related to cookies or seasons

As I'm at the first staged, unlogged in, the through ajax I logged in
the php start the session and create the cookies right?, but this session
or cookies are not accesible or don't exist in my current page (from where I nade the login ajax call).

So maybe php is preventing from fetching content of a logged in section (where session and cookies exit) from an unlogged in page (where there are not cookies or session initiated)

Does it make any sense?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Two things that I noted: #1 - you don't have a `semicolon` closing the AJAX response you're having a problem with, and, success is type 200, you can't get success without 200, so checking for if = success is redundant and a waste of time and space. Also, make sure you're sending the right MIME-type back, although Plain-text shouldn't be an issue. Anyway, it looks like OBJECT is the JSOn response from your php file and needs to be parsed. like $Html.name

Comment: I like your namespacing "js-" where did you get it from?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks for the answer but you're not correct in Any suggestion.

#1 Semicolons on javascript are not mandatory

#2 res.type == "success" is making reference to json response I got from the ajax call. It is not making reference to the ajax object

#3 The Mime-type is not important because I'm telling jquery how I want to handle the response, if you know what dataType params means in $.ajax

#4 Object is making reference to jsXHR Object or the XMLRequest Object, which is the first param in error callback, the second is the type, and 3rd one is the error message which is blank btw

Comment: @daemonfire300 I got from here http://ozmm.org/posts/slightly_obtrusive_javascript.html The idea is to separate style selectors (css) from funtional selector

Comment: @Cristian Andrés Araya Jiménez - You're right on a few areas. one thing you're wrong about is saying `Semicolons are not mandatory in JavaScript`. This is a general statement and is completely incorrect for anyone coming here from the future. There are plenty of scenario's where a semicolon are required.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: @Cristian Andrés Araya Jiménez Nice Article. It fails to mention several important instances where `semicolons are requried` such as `switch and break statements`. Anyway, keep on trucking.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax error callback can take up to 3 parameters `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`
It would be interresting to log the last one because it will contains the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but this looks like a function call to a chained function to me :

```
if($isValid.form()) {...}
```

but if it's working, and you're getting to the Ajax call's I suppose it's ok.

Your second ajax call seems to be missing a comma between the success and error handlers, and that's probably the reason you're not getting anything relevant in your console either :

Try:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/ajax/getheader',
    dataType:'html',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $('#header').html(data);
    },
    error:function() {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Good point. You are 100% correct, However it didn't fixed, In my code I have it correctly, may be when I copy paste the function I misspelled it. Just to clarify `$isValid = $(this).validate({...` is just the jquery validator plugin, and `$isValid.form()` is the function you call to actually validate the form... Thanks for you suggestion though